# How To delete object Array in objects state react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to remove the items from each of `saveProduct`s inside each `storeData` object

```js
const initialState = {
  storeData: [{
      "code": "f1",
      "name": "storage-no-1",
      "saveProducts": [{
          "code": "P1",
          "id": "1",
          "name": "product-no-1",
          "size": 20,
        },
        {
          "code": "P1",
          "id": "2",
          "name": "product-no-2",
          "size": 20,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "f2",
      "name": "storage-no-2",
      "saveProducts": [{
          "code": "P1",
          "id": "1",
          "name": "product-no-1",
          "size": 20,
        },
        {
          "code": "P1",
          "id": "2",
          "name": "product-no-2",
          "size": 20,
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = initialState;
  }

  deleteItem(saveProductsId, storeCode) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      prevState.storeData.map(store => {
        if (store.code == storeCode) {
          return {
            ...store,
            saveProducts: [
              ...store.saveProducts.filter(product => product !== saveProductsId)
            ]
          };
        } else {
          return store;
        }
      })
    })
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You miss to return inside your setState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code

1) You are not returning the new state when you are inside the state,

```
 this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
```

here you are actually returning the new state.

so, your code should look like this

```
this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState, storeData: prevState.storeData.map(store => {          
          if (store.code == storeCode) {
            return {
              ...store,
              saveProducts: [
                ...store.saveProducts.filter(product => product.id !== saveProductsId)
              ]
            };
          } else {
            return store;
          }
        })
      }
    })
```

2) You are comparing `...store.saveProducts.filter(product => product !== saveProductsId)` here you need `product.id` instead of `product`

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-voyhju)

Answer (score 2):

You need return new state in setState

```
deleteItem = (saveProductsId, storeCode) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {...prevState, storeData: prevState.storeData.map(store => {
                if (store.code == storeCode) {
                    return {
                        ...store,
                        saveProducts: [
                            ...store.saveProducts.filter(product => product !== saveProductsId)
                        ]
                    };
                } else {
                    return store;
                }
            })
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the computed result!

```
deleteItem(saveProductsId, storeCode) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return prevState.storeData.map(store => { // add return on this line
        if (store.code == storeCode) {
          return {
             ...store,
             saveProducts: [
                ...store.saveProducts.filter(product => product !== saveProductsId)
              ]
           };
         } else {
            return store;
        }
      })
    })
  };
```